# In Vulkan can I receive notification in the form of a callback when a command buffer is finished?

Tags: vulkan

I want to know when a command buffer has finished executing in Vulkan but rather than check myself regularly on a fence I was wondering if I could set a callback to be notified. Is this possible? The only callback I've seen I've seen mentioned is for something relating to allocations.

Answer (score 1):

Vulkan is a explicit, low-level API. One of the design choices in such an API is that the graphics driver gets CPU time only when *you* give it CPU time (in theory). This allows your code more control over the CPU and its threads.

In order for Vulkan to call your code back at arbitrary times, it would have to have a CPU thread on which to do it. But as previously stated, that's not a thing Vulkan implementations are expected to have.

Even the allocation callbacks are only called in the scope of a Vulkan API function which performs those allocations. That is, the asynchronous processing of a Vulkan queue doesn't do allocations.

So you're going to have to either check manually or block a thread on the fence until it is released.